# Why should the clients of MQTT choose their own id?

Tags: mqtt

I'm studying about MQTT v5.

When a MQTT client tries to connect with some broker, the client should provide its own client id.

If the client has never connected to the broker, the client should create a unique(different from any other clients) id.

In this case, I think the broker should create unique id for newcomer because the broker knows every clients' ids so it can generate unique id!

What is the benefit of letting clients choose their own ID?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the clear session option. If the server chooses the client ID, it could be different every time and two clients could have the same ID at different times (one disconnects and a new client connects and receives the same id).
This way if you set the clear session to false two clients could automatically subscribe, at different times, to the same topics (and receive all sent messages while he was offline) or a client cannot automatically reconnect (and receive old messages) because the server gives it a new ID.
If you imagine a situation where two clients need to subscribe to different topics and you set the clear session to false then they could get wrong messages from wrong topics

Answer (score 0):

MQTT allows Broker to assign Client ID.

In MQTT v3.1.1, the assigned Client ID cannot be returned to the client, so the client just asks the Broker to assign a new Client ID again the next time it reconnects, which will cause the client to fail to reuse sessions between connections.

However, in MQTT 5.0, the assigned Client ID will be returned in the CONNACK packet. So in MQTT 5.0, whether to let the Broker assign the Client ID or not depends more on your scenario, such as whether your device already have pre-assigned Client ID.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you should specify a client ID if you want the broker to remember your subscriptions when you are disconnected so that when you reconnect it can give you the messages that arrived for you while you were disconnected.

The longer answer is this...

MQTT supports "persistent sessions". With a persistent session, the broker will remember your subscriptions and hold any messages for you when you disconnect. That can be if you're accidentally disconnected or if you cleanly disconnect.

To get a persistent session, you specify `clean_session=false` (for v3) or `clean_start=false` (for v5).

That means, if you're just publishing or you just want to observe messages while you're connected, then you don't need a persistent session, and you don't need a Client ID.

But a general rule of thumb is that if you're using `clean_start=true`, then you don't need to specify your own ID. But if you're using `clean_start=false`, then you should give the broker a unique ID that you will also use when you reconnect.